# what to do with opencv_core245d.dll C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

Im working on VS professional 2012 but I want to use OpenCV on it but this problem happen: (opencv_core245d.dll is missing)

Comment: Put it into your working directory or add its path to PATH variable

Comment: I added the path 
but it still exist

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file into your project folder - this is the universally easiest solution.

Comment: where can i found the file ?

Comment: Depends if you downloaded the library pre-built or linked it yourself as per http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation. 
To use the OpenCV library you have two options: Installation by Using the Pre-built Libraries or Installation by Making Your Own Libraries from the Source Files. While the first one is easier to complete, it only works if you are coding with the latest Microsoft Visual Studio IDE and doesn’t take advantage of the most advanced technologies we integrate into our library.

Comment: The actual file will be somewhere inside a bin/ folder in your opencv folder.